# Xcode9 Realm Error - No viable overloaded ‘=’

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I just install Xcode 9 and build my native iOS project. (Is written in swift)

The project was OK in Xcode 8 but now, I obtain this error:

`No viable overloaded '='`

In the file: Pods\Pods\Realm\object.cpp

Line 42 => `m_notifier = std::make_shared<_impl::ObjectNotifier>(m_row, m_realm);`

Comment: What's the type of ```m_notifier```? It might be that the base class didn't properly overload the = operator

Comment: thank you for reply.Type is `_impl::CollectionNotifier::Handle<_impl::ObjectNotifier> m_notifier;` in  `Object` class.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using Cocoapods, open up the Podfile and set the RealmSwift version to 2.8.1 (or 2.8.3 as David mentioned above). Here is my Podfile for Swift 3.0 using Xcode 9:

```
target ‘<PROJECT>’ do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods
  ...
  pod 'RealmSwift', '2.8.1'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Then, save the file and run:

> pod install

If you're not setting a specific pod version (which I recommend), run the following command:

> pod update RealmSwift

and it will automatically update to the most recent version (2.8.3).

Hope it helps to complement David's answer. Thanks!

Comment: My source code is written in `Objective-C`. So I have used `pod 'Realm', '2.8.3'` and it is worked.

Answer (score 8):

The Realm team has worked on a new version allowing you to build your project with XCode 9. 
Just update your Realm version to at least `2.8.1` (current version is `2.8.3`)

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases/tag/v2.8.1

The Realm release note of `2.8.1` clearly states :

> Add support for building with Xcode 9 Beta 1.